# How to create an ISO 8601 Date Formatter with milliseconds and timezone in Swift?

Tags: swift, datetime, foundation

I need an ISO 8601 date formatter ***With Milliseconds and Timezone*** in Swift.

Here's a sample date object:

```
'2017-06-03T01:04:17.826050+00:00'
```

The documentations seem to require a date with the following format:  `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.mmmmmm+HH:MM`, which is ISO 8601 if I'm correct.

But attempting to create a DateFormatter with that format doesn't seem to work:

```
var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.mmmmmm+HH:MM"
dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
```

Which outputs `2017-06-154`, which is not the expected format.

The standard `ISODateFormatter()` also does not output the expected format.

Comment: Where did you find that (wrong) documentation? Here is the right one: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: It's the documentation of requirements for the project